# Do I need a visa for Basel if I hold a Jamaican Passport but have British Citizenship Residency

Tags: visas, schengen, transit, paperwork, bsl

I am travelling on my Jamaican passport from Hurghada to Basel but I hold a British Citizenship - do I need a visa or can I show my Residency card when changing planes - I am just changing planes back to the UK.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do I need a visa to transit (or layover) in the Schengen area?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-or-layover-in-the-schengen-area)

Comment: If you're a British citizen, why don't you have a British passport? You'll need it to do this visa-free

Comment: @HenningMakholm Dangerous advice; BSL doesn't have a transit corridor

Comment: As noted, if you are a citizen, you would need to travel with a passport. After becoming a citizen, a Biometric Residence Permit (BRP) is no longer appropriate, and has to be turned into the Home Office within 5 days of becoming a citizen. While you may enter the UK with a BRP, but it cannot be used to enter Schengen; for that you would require a visa if you are not a British citizen passport holder.

Comment: I'd suggest not to close, as the "dupe" doesn't make it clear BSL lacks transit facilities

Answer (score 4):

Basel doesn't have a transit corridor, so you will clear immigration, go through arrivals to departures and clear exit immigration, and as such need to fulfil the requirements for entering the Schengen Area.

If you're a British citizen (eligible for a British passport) you can do this visa-free on a British passport.

If you only have a Jamaican passport, you need a type C Schengen visa.